# How to create new email account on WHMCS client area

Tags: cpanel, whmcs

I think need some help to do that. My WHMCS system is create Cpanel user. When i login as client I'm showing login Webmail, Login Cpanel, change password cpanel and all feature is working fine.

But i want to create email account but i don't add it. How to create email account on cpanel via WHMCS? Any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an email account is a built in feature of the cPanel module in the six theme of WHMCS. If you want to see how to extend this to add additional options or do more control, you can check out this presentation I made for the cPanel Conference:

https://github.com/n8whnp/cPconf-2015/blob/master/cP-Conf-2015-Customizing-WHMCS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

No, You can not create mail account through WHMCS. You need to login your cPanel to create mail account OR Access server through SSH with the root user login details and then create mail account through cPanel script(/scripts/addpop).

Comment: My client can't create email account o whhmcs client area? I didn't found any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create email account directly from WHMCS. You have to log in to cPanel first from direct URL or from client area and then you can create the email account from Email Section.

Also, you can create email account by SSH Access.